# Why is rails not showing my API call results?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty

I’m completely new to ruby on rails,  I’m creating a simple article search application that would use the Guardian API and just display the news titles.
I made a simple view, controller and a class that makes calls to external API, but the results don’t show up on my page and I’m puzzled. It just needs to work this way: a user enters the page,  fills in the search form and views the news titles. I’m using httparty gem.

API consumer class:

```rb
#app/clients/guardian_api_client.rb

class GuardianApiClient
  include HTTParty  

  API_KEY = ENV['GUARDIAN_CONTENT_API_KEY']
  BASE_URL ="https://content.guardianapis.com/search?" 
  API_PARTIAL_URL = "api-key=#{API_KEY}"


  def query(q)
      request = HTTParty.get(BASE_URL+"q=#{q}&""api-key=#{API_KEY}")
      puts request
  end

end
```

Controller:

```rb
class SearchController < ApplicationController
    def search
        @app = GuardianApiClient.new
        @results = @app.query(params[:q])
    end
end
```

View:

```rb
<%= form_with(url: '/search') do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :q %>
<%= f.submit 'search' %>
<% end %>

<% if @results != nil %>
  <ul>
  <%= @results.each do |r| %>
  <li><%= r["webTitle"] %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
<% else %>
  <p>No results yet</p>
<% end %>
```

Routes:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/search' => 'search#search'
  post '/search' => 'search#search'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the API client you print the results with `puts`:

```
  def query(q)
      request = HTTParty.get(BASE_URL+"q=#{q}&""api-key=#{API_KEY}")
      puts request
  end
```

`puts` returns `nil`, so controller doesn't get the results. You need to return request from your `query` method:

```
  def query(q)
      request = HTTParty.get(BASE_URL+"q=#{q}&""api-key=#{API_KEY}")
      puts request
      request
  end
```

(ruby returns the result of the last call in the method).

Comment: Thank you! The results shows up on the page now, however, it's a large array of hashes, not only the titles of articles. Is there any easy way to display only titles ?

Comment: you need to select them.  Ask another question and pastet here what is shown.

Comment: I pasted the request result in this post:    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58846594/how-to-select-data-from-api-call-result-in-rails